# c# Cryptography that works for windows phone 7 and 8 app, silverlight clients and windows tablet apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, cryptography, windows-store-apps

I'm looking for a cryptography example in c# that demonstrates how to use encryption/decryption that works for:
- Silverlight Clients
- Windows Tablet Apps
- Windows Phone 7 and 8 Apps

Actually we have found examples that work either on one of the platforms but not on the others. Mostly this seems because e.g. Namespace where IBuffer (used in Windows Phone 8 Examples) is located seems not to be available in Silverlight Clients.
Other Problem is, that for example the class Rfc2898DeriveBytes seems not to have an equal counterpart in namespaces for Windows Phone Apps and, at most for me, it seems hard to Derivate the appropriate classes, KeySizes, Salts usw. to reproduce the same encryption result as code generates with Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.

So, does anybody have a link to a good example about encryption/decryption working on ALL the platforms named above?

Thanks for your help.
Adrian

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please specify "good". We need to be able to determine whether an example is "good" or not to be able to answer your question and we do not know what is good for you. Please, edit your question and make sure that we can determine about any post whether it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/) product (including its free with source [CryptoBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cryptobb.php) cryptographic package ) will do the job as it's available for all mentioned platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the the simple answer is: There isn't one out of the box. If you want one library that will work across all of those platforms, you'll need to find a third-party one. Microsoft has not provided one.

That being said, there is still a way to make it so that your business logic can still be platform-less (such as in a PCL) while still harnessing the platform-specific encryption methods. This is using Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control (IoC).

Basically, create an `ICryptoController` class. This class will define all of the cryptographic functions that you want to do. If you want to do an AES function, create methods:

`Task<byte[]> AesEncrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data, byte[] iv);`

`Task<byte[]> AesDecrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data, byte[] iv);`

I should note that I suggest using byte arrays (byte[]) as your return and input values, as they are cross-platform, whereas the IBuffers on WP8 and Win8 are not.

Then, what you do is create a `ServiceLocator` class in your PCL that contains a `static`, accessible `ICryptoController` property.

On each platform, create a `CryptoController` class which implements `ICryptoController`. It then overrides each crypto function with the platform-specific implementation. WPF may use System.Security. Windows Store apps will use SymmetricAlgorithmProvider, etc.

(For example, if you look it up, Rfc2898DeriveBytes is actually just PBKDF2, Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2. Windows Store provides functionality to do this via the `KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider` class. There are guides to doing this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh802421.aspx).)

At the start of each app on each platform, set the value of the property in your `ServiceLocator` to the platform-specific version. Your PCL classes now have free access to the platform-specific implementations of the cryptographic algorithms.

There are plenty of Service Locator libraries out there. Ninject is one, though there are many others. One is included in MvvmLight, for instance. They will make it quite easy to implement (though it's not particularly hard).

Hope this helps and happy coding!

As a last note, I know there are some people that have attempted to port over BouncyCastle to the different platforms. I have not yet found an implementation that is `Portable` though. If you want to reduce the amount of crypto systems you have to learn, you may want to see how many of those systems you need have a viable BouncyCastle implementation that you can trust. I believe there are two available for Win8, for instance, though I can't vouch for their authors.