# Cryptography that works for windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows, winforms, cryptography, windows-store-apps

Following on from question
[c# Cryptography that works for windows phone 7 and 8 app, silverlight clients and windows tablet apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777764/c-sharp-cryptography-that-works-for-windows-phone-7-and-8-app-silverlight-clien)

I am trying to figure out the body of the functions for a windows store app and a windows 7 app.

Task AesEncrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data, byte[] iv);

Task AesDecrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data, byte[] iv);

For the windows 7 the following code works

```
    Dim Password As String = "PasswordPassword"
    Dim data1 As String = "Some test data to check this encodes correctly  "

    Dim PasswordBA = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password.ToArray)
    Dim EncIVBA() As Byte = {183, 124, 217, 35, 247, 115, 33, 34, 191, 47, 186, 52, 54, 145, 56, 14}

    ' Encrypt the data. 
    Dim encAlg = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create()
    encAlg.Key = PasswordBA
    encAlg.IV = EncIVBA
    Dim encryptionStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim encrypt As New CryptoStream(encryptionStream, encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    Dim utfD1 As Byte() = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False).GetBytes(data1)
    encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length)
    encrypt.FlushFinalBlock()
    encrypt.Close()
    Dim edata1 As Byte() = encryptionStream.ToArray() ' 40, 104 ..
    IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Local\Packages\5ff3fe41-65d0-4e09-b1db-9082e9763abb_e4zkcfr8ebjb0\LocalState\ForWin8.dat", edata1)

    ' Decrypt, thus showing it can be round-tripped. 
    'Dim EData2 = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\ForWin8.dat")
    Dim EData2 = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Local\Packages\5ff3fe41-65d0-4e09-b1db-9082e9763abb_e4zkcfr8ebjb0\LocalState\ForWin7.dat")
    Dim decAlg = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create
    decAlg.Key = PasswordBA
    decAlg.IV = EncIVBA
    Dim decryptionStreamBacking As New MemoryStream()
    Dim decrypt As New CryptoStream(decryptionStreamBacking, decAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    decrypt.Write(edata2, 0, edata2.Length)
    decrypt.Flush()
    decrypt.Close()
    Dim data2 As String = New UTF8Encoding(False).GetString(decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray())

    If Not data1.Equals(data2) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error: The two values are not equal.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("The two values are equal.")
    End If
```

and in windows 8 the following works

```
    ' encrypt
    Dim data1 As String = "Some test data to check this encodes correctly"
    Dim Data1Len = data1.Length
    Dim Data1LenPad = ((Data1Len - 1) Or 15) + 1
    data1 = data1.PadRight(Data1LenPad, " "c)
    Dim algname = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc
    Dim alg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algname)
    Dim pw = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("PasswordPassword", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)
    Dim bl = alg.BlockLength
    Dim buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data1, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)

    Dim EncIVBA() As Byte = {183, 124, 217, 35, 247, 115, 33, 34, 191, 47, 186, 52, 54, 145, 56, 14}
    Dim EncIV = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data1, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)

    Dim key = alg.CreateSymmetricKey(pw)
    Dim Enc = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffMsg, EncIV)

    Dim EncLen = Enc.Length
    Dim Encba As Byte()
    ReDim Encba(CInt(EncLen - 1))
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Enc, Encba)

    Dim file1 As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("ForWin7.dat", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
    Dim fileStream1 As Stream = Await file1.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()
    fileStream1.Write(Encba, 0, Encba.Length)
    Await fileStream1.FlushAsync()

    'Dim file As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ForWin7.dat")
    Dim file As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ForWin8.dat")
    Dim Enc2 = Await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)

    Dim Data2Buf = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, Enc2, EncIV)
    Dim Data2 = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, Data2Buf)

    If Not data1.Equals(Data2) Then
        Dim Status = "Error: The two values are not equal."
    Else
        Dim Status = "The two values are equal."
    End If
```

but the files are not the same.  The Windows 7 code can not decode the file generated by the Windows 8 code and vice versa.

What encode and decode algorithm is common between Windows 7 and Windows 8?

Comment: I recommend you to set the Mode and Padding explictly in both sources. In your case Aes to CBC mode and Padding to Pkcs7.

Comment: I tried that but it still had different outputs and could not load between win7 and win8.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 you are using EncIV as EncIVBA but in Windows 8 code you are using data1 ("Some test data to check this encodes correctly") as EncIV, that should output very different results. 
Sometimes the problem looks really tough but is really simple hahaha, I got lucky on this one.